# Mapping Observable array of one type to an Observable array of a different type

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, observable

I am working on a data service that gets data from a REST service. Is there a way to receive an Observable of an array of one type of object but return an Observable of a different type of array? I would think this is what mergeMap does but I'm having trouble understanding how to accomplish this.

Something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyDataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getThings(): Observable<B[]> {
    return this.http.get<A[]>(url)
    mergeMap(x => [x + <B>{foo: x.bar});
  }
}
```

In C# I would just use a LINQ expression to select a new object. How can I do the same thing in Angular? Perhaps the service can just simply return the Observable array of type A and the consumer that's subscribed to the service can take care of the mapping somehow? Would that be the better approach?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what/where you want to map. For example you can type hint the `.map` operator:

```
.map<A, B>(v => /* transform A to B */)
```

You can do the same with `mergeMap`:

```
.mergeMap<A, B>(v => /* transform A to Observable<B> */)
```

Comment: I found I had to do a mapping twice to get what I wanted. The first map call 'x' is a A[]. But I need to change each A into a B so I mapped x and returned a new B using the y variable in the second map. Is there a better way?



`.map(x => x.map(y => <B>{ foo: bar }))`

Comment: I think you can return also `.map(x => x.map(y => { foo: bar })) as B[]` which is maybe more readable